# Remove 1st value in 2D array if they are same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having this type of array

```
array = [
  ["01000290056", 601, "Individu─ülo dz─½vojamo m─üju apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  ["01000290056", 703, "Se┼Īu l─½dz se┼Īpadsmit st─üvu daudzdz─½vok─╝u m─üju apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  ["01000290056", 801, "Komercdarb─½bas objektu apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  ["01000290056", 1001, "R┼½pniecisk─üs ra┼Šo┼Īanas uz┼å─ōmumu apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  ["01000290056", 1105, "Atsevi┼Ī─Ęi nodal─½tas atkl─ütas autost─üvvietas", nil, 0]
]
```

In this case, `01000290056` is repeating.

In the end, I need to get something like this

```
[["01000290056", 601, "Individu─ülo dz─½vojamo m─üju apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
 [nil, 703, "Se┼Īu l─½dz se┼Īpadsmit st─üvu daudzdz─½vok─╝u m─üju apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
 [nil, 801, "Komercdarb─½bas objektu apb┼½ve", nil, 0], 
 [nil, 1001, "R┼½pniecisk─üs ra┼Šo┼Īanas uz┼å─ōmumu apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
 [nil, 1105, "Atsevi┼Ī─Ęi nodal─½tas atkl─ütas autost─üvvietas", nil, 0]]
```

So all duplicated values of `01000290056` should be removed.

Im trying it do to in this way

```
array.each_with_index.map do |v,i|
  v.each_with_index.map do |k,j|
    if (i-1>=0 && k == array[i-1][j])
      k
    elsif (i+1 < array.length && k == array[i+1][j])
      k
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

But it returns me this:

```
[["01000290056", nil, nil, nil, 0],
 ["01000290056", nil, nil, nil, 0],
 ["01000290056", nil, nil, nil, 0],
 ["01000290056", nil, nil, nil, 0],
 ["01000290056", nil, nil, nil, 0]]
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: What's `outcome`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Fixed. It's an array. Forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'set'

f = Set.new

array.map do |a|
  f.add?(a.first) ? a : [nil, *a.drop(1)]
end
  #=> [["01000290056", 601, "Individu─ülo dz─½vojamo m─üju apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  #    [nil, 703, "Se┼Īu l─½dz se┼Īpadsmit...", nil, 0],
  #    [nil, 801, "Komercdarb─½bas objektu apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  #    [nil, 1001, "R┼½pniecisk─üs ra┼Šo┼Īanas uz┼å─ōmumu apb┼½ve", nil, 0],
  #    [nil, 1105, "Atsevi┼Ī─Ęi nodal─½tas atkl─ütas autost─üvvietas", nil, 0]]
```

This does not modify or *mutate* `array`.

If `array` is to be modified, you could use the following.

```
f = Set.new

array.each { |a| a[0] = nil unless f.add?(a.first) }
array
```

Making `f` a set, rather than array, speeds lookups, which could be important if `array` were large.

See [Set::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new), [Set#add?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) and [Array#drop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-drop).

Answer (score 1):

> What is my mistake?

Judging by input and output, you forgot what were you supposed to do, and started iterating through every element of every sub-array.

One common method to avoid confusion is to [use comments for planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)#Planning_and_reviewing).

Here's my solution:

```rb
def remove_firsts(arr)
  # Make sure first elements in sub-arrays are equal
  if arr.map { |sub_arr| sub_arr[0] }.uniq.length == 1
    # iterate through all elements except first
    (1...arr.length).each do |i|
      arr[i][0] = nil
    end
  end
  return arr
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping nil when iterating each element of the inner subarrays and keeping only the identical values.

I suggest this simpler solution that should do what you asked:

```
dups = []
array.map{|a| dups.include?(a[0]) ? a[0] = nil : dups << a[0]; a }
```

Basically we don't need to loop the whole inner arrays, I just check the first element and if it has been already met, set it to nil.

Note that this map function will act on the original array, mutating it, if you want to preserve the original data you should duplicate it before mapping as I suggested.